# Why the blue bar on the left edge of the code tag rectangle on superuser.com?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

SuperUser, unlike StackOverflow and Meta has a very weird code box. It has a thick blue edge on the left, which is very distracting.

[image]

I would prefer a clean box like this

[image]

I don't know why this unnecessary thing was introduced on SuperUser, but with the colour combinations that SuperUser has, it looks odd and not at all nice, specially in `code` (`""` are still okay).

**Is there any chance that these dark blue things are removed?** OR is there some very good reason to keep them?

Comment: They weren't there initially, they have been added on request, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8446/su-blockquotes

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10994/can-we-have-superuser-blockquote-formatting-in-stackoverflow-et-al and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/increase-contrast-of-block-quote-code-block

Comment: @fretje: thanks for fetching those links!

Comment: images are broken

Answer (score 3):

After looking at one of my posts on SuperUser, I think the blue bar is there because the background of the code/quote box is too close to that of the rest of the site.

I could barely tell that there was anything different about the background (other than the blue bar).

Maybe a slightly darker background would fix the problem the blue bar was meant to solve...as well as get rid of the ugly blue bar.